# bash subshell vs vanilla command execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As far as I know, when you run a command, like

```
> sleep 3
```

The shell process will fork another process and run the command with the child process.

However when you do

```
> (sleep 3)
```

you launch a subshell and execute the command. Essentially what it does is also fork another process to execute the command and wait the command to complete.

In this case, the behavior of the two commands looks the same, the parent shell will wait the sleep command to complete.

However sometime I noticed things are different with subshell:

For example, if I run some command like:

```
> virtualbox &
```

If I accidentally close the terminal the virtualbox will close at the same time. I already screwed my ongoing work several time in this way.

However if I do it this way it the program won't be killed even if I exited the terminal:

```
> (virtualbox &)
```

So I am not sure what's going on under the hood? How are the tasks started and managed by the shell with the two different approach?

Comment: it's not your question but you should use `nohup` to ensure continuation of your program.

Comment: Actually that's helpful. Next time I will launch virtualbox with nohup not subshell.

Comment: if your system has `ptree`, use that to see the difference between `vbox` and `(vbox &)`. OR some `ps` tools have a `-T` option for `tree` display. In both you'll see the parent / child relationships, OR if a process has been disassociated from the parent. Actually, `nohup` or `screen` or `tmux` are probably really all you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

As others write, using *nohup* will allow you to run the process without it being terminated when your shell is terminated.  What happens in the two cases you describe is the following.

- In the `virtualbox &` case *virtualbox* becomes a child of your shell.  When your controlling terminal is closed all processes associated with it receive a *SIGHUP* signal, and are terminated.
- In the `(virtualbox &)` case the command is executed within a subshell.  When the subshell terminates, the command is disassociated from the shell and the terminal. (You can see this by running *ps*.) In this case the *SIGHUP* will not be sent to *virtualbox*, and therefore your command will not be terminated when the controlling terminal is closed.

The *nohup* command achieves the same result by specifying that the *SIGHUP* signal must be ignored.